# possible to add a letter to an ID but it still autonumbers

Tags: database, auto-increment

I Have database called books.

I want to have the ID's in say books db to be B1, B2 etc and then just keep incrementing the number automatically.

Is this automatically done by the system or would I have to make the ID's myself when inserting anything into the db??

Note I'm using php.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Will depend on your database.  Optionally a multi column PK using a static column for the prefix with an auto increment (aka sequence) might work for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only type of ID that can be auto-incremented is a number based ID.

Anything else you would have to put in manually (or hackily in the database which is **not** recommended)

Comment: Maybe not with MySQL.  Pretty sure you can in Oracle PL/SQL.  ...Ok, giving you the upvote still.  Think it still involves a trigger which I suppose some people consider "hackish".

Answer (score 1):

I think you should keep the ids as integer and if you want to display it to the user as B1, B2, etc just do so and remove the 'B' when its time to make database calls.